# How can I solve this?? The serve command requires to be run in an Angular project, but a project definition could not be found

Tags: angular, npm-install

I know that this question already was on Stackoverflow, **and I'm sorry for it**, but I didn't get my right answer, so this is a situation:
I try to run my project and I get this error --

> The serve command requires to be run in an Angular project, but a
>   project definition could not be found.

1. Project was cloned from git and it is of elder vervion of Angular5.
2. I tried to -npm install , -npm update, -ng i @angular/cli.
3. Tried to unistall and clean cache.
4. I -ng serve it in the right directory

So what I can do more to solve this issue???

Comment: Are you trying to run `ng serve` and `npm install` commands from the project directory folder?

Comment: Yes, sure as I wrote in question

Answer (score 0):

Try these,

1. If you are running any commands like `npm install` or `ng serve`, always ensure that you are running them from the project‘s root directory. Eg: where your `package.json` & `angular.json` files are located.
2. If you find a file named `angular-cli.json` instead of `angular.json`, you need to run this command,

   ```
   ng update @angular/cli --migrate-only --from=your_older_angular_cli_version_here
   ```

   For example if your older **Angular CLI** version is 1.0.0,

   ```
   ng update @angular/cli --migrate-only --from=1.0.0
   ```
3. If the above fixes didn’t help, Try this command,

   ```
   ng update --all --force
   ```